# How to add new line in grafana alerting template?

Tags: grafana

We´re on Grafana open-source v. 9.2.3.

The docs says there are no html functionality when designing the alert message template.
I want to get the best out of our working message template.
The thing is that my received alert output(email) looks messy and does not separate each panel alert text per line.
How to make this work in Grafanas alert rule configuration?